# How to manipulate the contents of a button without using id; Android?

Tags: android, xml, button, onclick

I'm new in android world and I have a problem, well, I'm making a project very simple it is about an activity where i have a button and an EditText. The button has an event onClick in XML.
My problem is it: I need the button value and send this value to
EditText but my button don't have a id. Help me I don't know how manipulate a element if it dont have a id.

XML Code:

```
 <View 
             android:layout_height="@dimen/cell_height"
             android:background="@color/red"/>
         <Button 
             android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/button_margin"
             android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
             android:text="@string/hex_red"
             android:textColor="@color/red"
             android:onClick="copy"/>`
```

Java code:

```
public void copy(View boton){

    EditText txtSelected = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtColor)

    String color =  boton; <-- here need the button value

    txtSelected.setText(color);
}
```

I need your help, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onClickBtn(View view) {

EditText txtSelected = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtColor)


Button btn = (Button)(view);
String value = (String) btn.getText();
txtSelected.setText(value);
txtSelected.setSelection(value.length()); // cursor will be at the end of the text

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can say boton.getText().toString()

Comment: cast the view to button like this Button button=(Button)boton

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `copy()` function like this:

```
public void copy(View boton) {
  EditText txtSelected = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtColor)

  Button btn = (Button) boton;  // << key point.
  String color = btn.getText().toString();

  txtSelected.setText(color);
}`
```